# Line break javascript doesn't insert new line "\n"

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, textarea

I've been trying to wrap my head around this whole line break thing, and I've searched and researched my soul out here. I can't seem to find an answer to my specific problem here. I want to fetch the input from a textarea and put it in an array with new lines. All it does is put a comma between the words, and it seems it only adds multiple commas to where the line breaks are supposed to be. When I add < br / >, all it does is exclude the letter b from the text.

```
function Wordscount() {
                var pText = document.getElementById("myTextarea").value.split(/[\n <>.,\?]/);
                document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = pText;
```

It basically just looks like this when I test it :

[image: It basically just looks like this when I test it]

I am new to Javascript, and I wouldn't have gone for this solution unless this was the method our professor told us to use. I'm really frustrated here, and I'm just trying to get the hang of this.

Comment: What do you think .split() is doing?

Comment: Maybe you should search for \r\n instead of \n

Comment: I tried adding \r\n, and it doesn't make a difference. According to what we learned, .split() is used for splitting characters, words etc.

Comment: *"fetch the input from a textarea and put it in an array with new lines"* what do you think is an array? What result do you expect? basically, how would it look "correct" and why is the current result not right?

Comment: The array is supposed to have the words in alphabetical order with word frequency. That's why this isn't correct.

Answer (score 2):

Splitting a string turns it into an array. Treating an array as a string is equivalent to calling `yourArray.join(',')`. Since you don't want to add commas, don't just treat the array as a string.

If you want to put HTML line breaks in, then you need to do so explicitly.

```
var array_of_lines = document.getElementById("myTextarea").value.split("\n");
var string_of_html = array_of_lines.join("<br>");
document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = string_of_html;
```

If you don't want HTML special characters to be treated as having special meaning, then convert each line to a text node and append it instead.

```
var array_of_lines = document.getElementById("myTextarea").value.split("\n");
document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "";
while(var text = array_of_lines.unshift()) {
    document.getElementById("text").appendChild(
        document.createTextNode(text)
    );
    document.getElementById("text").appendChild(
        document.createElement("br")
    );
}
```